# A problem on an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1+\dfrac{1}{3}.\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}.\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{7}.\dfrac{1}{4^3}+.......$

My efforts:

=$1$+$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2i-1}.\dfrac{1}{4^{(2i-1)}}$

=$1$+$\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k}.\dfrac{1}{2^{2k}}$ where $k=k+2$

i.e $1+\dfrac{1}{3}.\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{5}.\dfrac{1}{2^4}+\dfrac{1}{7}.\dfrac{1}{2^6}+.....$

or

we can write $1$+$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2i-1}.\dfrac{1}{4^{(2i-1)}}$

$>$ $1$+$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2i}.\dfrac{1}{4^{(2i-1)}}$

=$1$+$\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2i}.\dfrac{4}{4^{(2i)}}$

=$1$+$4\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2i}.\dfrac{1}{4^{(2i)}}$

=$1$+$2\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i}.\dfrac{1}{4^{(2i)}}$

=$1+2(1+\dfrac{1}{2}.\dfrac{1}{4^4}+\dfrac{1}{3}.\dfrac{1}{4^6}-1)$

=$1+2(-ln(1-\dfrac{1}{4^4})-1)$=$2ln(\dfrac{256}{255})-1$

Comment: What do you mean by "$k=k+2$" ?

Comment: In the first line $2(i-1) $ is wrong. It is $2i-1$. The second line completely wrong.

Comment: @MattiP. by that I mean $for(k=2;k<\infty;k=k+2)$

Comment: @ Saradamani: It should probably be $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2i-1}\cdot\frac{1}{4^{i-1}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}$$
let $x\rightarrow x^2$
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{2n}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}$$
divide by $x$
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{2x}\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}}$$
then let $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Crisp and elegant @E.H.E

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Rewrite this sum as $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac 1{(2n+1)\,2^{2n}}\;$ and solve the more general problem of calculating the sum
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n+1)}=\frac 1x\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}.$$